# Can I call a functional component inside a custom hook? Is it okay for such a hook to be a .tsx, not .ts files?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-typescript, react-custom-hooks

I made a custom hook that wraps Chakra's custom hook. Chakra UI is a component library.

```
export const useToast = () => {
  const chakraToast = useChakraToast();

  // ...

  const toast = ({ id, title, delay, position = `bottom-right` }: Options) => {
    return chakraToast({
      id,
      position,
      duration: null,
      render: ({ onClose }) => (<Toast title={title} onClose={onClose} />)
    });
  };

  // ...

  return toast;
};
```

As you can see, I need to tell Chakra to use my Toast component. The question is, is it okay to call a functional component in a custom hook? If so, I need to change the extension of my custom hook file from .ts to .tsx. Is it okay as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
export const useToast = () => {
  const chakraToast = useChakraToast();

  // ...

  const toast = ({ id, title, delay, position = `bottom-right` }: Options) => {
    return chakraToast({
      id,
      position,
      duration: null,
      render: ({ onClose }) => (<Toast title={title} onClose={onClose} />)
    });
  };

  // ...

  return toast;
};
```

> The question is, is it okay to call a functional component in a custom
> hook?

It seems you are specifically referring to the `render` function. As such, it seems a perfectly valid use of a render function that returns ***JSX***. From what I can tell, your question about function components is irrelevant. You are defining a function that returns ***JSX***.

See [Custom Component](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/feedback/toast#custom-component)

> If so, I need to change the extension of my custom hook file from `*.ts`
> to `*.tsx`. Is it okay as well?

I see no issue here. `*.jsx` and `*.tsx` (*vs `*.js` and `*.ts`*) only indicate that JSX syntax is used in the file. The [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) make no rules governing the files they can be declared in, but rather only how they are used.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer! It absolutely makes sense. And yes, I was referring to returning JSX from a render function